# Computer crashes while in incognito mode

Tags: google-chrome, bsod, windows-error-reporting, private-browsing

To summarise I was in incognito mode when my pc just showed the blue screen and fixing any errors being seen but it's been two days and it hasn't started up (it needs a new battery and a hard disk) so I can maybe guess it got too overloaded and couldn't take it with many apps being open...

my main concern is suppose it did get restarted will the tabs remain the same with the incognito mode contents being seen? Or will it just show the home page of the mode with the normal chrome tab open.
It might just cost my life if my parents knew I was on incognito-

Answer (score 0):

First, Chrome will not reopen in Incognito mode.

Second, Incognito mode is actually a very safe mode to work in, as all
extensions are disabled and websites will have difficulty in tracking you.
No need to fill ashamed - this isn't a hacking mode.
Some knowledgeable people prefer working in this mode by default.